# Sprite Kit detecting collision?

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, sprite-kit

How do you detect collision is sprite kit? it needs to work with my already existing code as i have tried one method and it failed. The game currently has a missile that falls from the sky and the space ship has to dodge them, i want it so if they collide that you lose a life. Here is my code

```
static const uint32_t shipCategory =  0x1 << 1;
static const uint32_t obstacleCategory =  0x1 << 1;

@implementation MyScene{

SKSpriteNode *ship;
SKSpriteNode *missile;
int score;
int HighScore;
SKAction *actionMoveRight;
SKAction *actionMoveLeft;
SKLabelNode *label;

}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
    [self addShip];

    //Making self delegate of physics World
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,0);
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

    //score
    score = 5;
    label = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
    label.fontSize = 40;
    label.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
    label.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
    [self addChild:label];

    //highscore
     HighScore  = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"];
    label = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",HighScore];
    label.fontSize = 40;
    label.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
    label.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/1, self.size.height/2);
    [self addChild:label];
    }

    return self;
}



-(void)addShip
{
    //initalizing spaceship node
    ship = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
    [ship setScale:0.5];
    ship.zRotation = - M_PI / 2;

    //Adding SpriteKit physicsBody for collision detection
    ship.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ship.size];
    ship.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = shipCategory;
    ship.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    ship.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = obstacleCategory;
    ship.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    ship.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    ship.name = @"ship";
    ship.position = CGPointMake(260,30);
    actionMoveRight = [SKAction moveByX:-30 y:0 duration:.2];
actionMoveLeft = [SKAction moveByX:30 y:0 duration:.2];

    [self addChild:ship];
}

- (void)shootMissile
{
// Sprite Kit knows that we are working with images so we don't need to pass the image’s                extension
missile = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"red-missile"];
[missile setScale:0.15];
// Position the missile outside the top
int r = arc4random() % 200;
missile.position = CGPointMake(20 + r, self.size.height + missile.size.height/2);
// Add the missile to the scene
[self addChild:missile];

// Here is the Magic
// Run a sequence
[missile runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                        // Move the missile and Specify the animation time
                                        [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-(self.size.height + missile.size.height) duration:5],
                                        // When the missile is outside the bottom
                                        // The missile will disappear
                                        [SKAction removeFromParent]
                                        ]
                    ]];
}

- (void)updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:(CFTimeInterval)timeSinceLast {

self.lastSpawnTimeInterval += timeSinceLast;
if (self.lastSpawnTimeInterval > 5) {
    self.lastSpawnTimeInterval = 0;
    [self shootMissile];
}
}
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
// Handle time delta.
// If we drop below 60fps, we still want everything to move the same distance.
CFTimeInterval timeSinceLast = currentTime - self.lastUpdateTimeInterval;
self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
if (timeSinceLast > 1) { // more than a second since last update
    timeSinceLast = 1.0 / 60.0;
    self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
}

[self updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:timeSinceLast];

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];
if(touchLocation.x >ship.position.x){
    if(ship.position.x < 270){
        [ship runAction:actionMoveLeft];
    }
}else{
    if(ship.position.x > 50){

        [ship runAction:actionMoveRight];
    }
}
}

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;
if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;
}
else
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyB;
    secondBody = contact.bodyA;
}

if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & shipCategory) != 0 &&
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask & obstacleCategory) != 0)
{

    score ++;
    if (score > HighScore) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score] forKey:@"HighScore"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
        SKScene * gameOverScene = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
        [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition: reveal];
    }
}
}






@end
```

Comment: Also i know how to minis a life etc i just need the collision detection bit.

Comment: - (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact will detect your collision...

Comment: You can check collision detection by grabbing both sky sprite node and space ship sprite node frames and check if they intersect with each other. And put the implementation of collision detection in your's game run loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new category for `missile`:

```
static const uint32_t missileCategory =  0x1 << 2;
```

Define `physicsBody` for `missile`:

```
missile.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:missile.size];
missile.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = missileCategory;
missile.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
missile.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = shipCategory;
missile.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
missile.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
```

Add this check into `didBeginContact` method:

```
if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & shipCategory) != 0 &&
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask & missileCategory) != 0)
{
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Here is a modified code:

```
static const uint32_t shipCategory =  0x1 << 1;
static const uint32_t obstacleCategory =  0x1 << 1;
static const uint32_t missileCategory =  0x1 << 2;

@implementation MyScene{

SKSpriteNode *ship;
SKSpriteNode *missile;
int score;
int HighScore;
SKAction *actionMoveRight;
SKAction *actionMoveLeft;
SKLabelNode *label;

}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
    [self addShip];

    //Making self delegate of physics World
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,0);
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

    //score
    score = 5;
    label = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
    label.fontSize = 40;
    label.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
    label.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
    [self addChild:label];

    //highscore
     HighScore  = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"];
    label = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",HighScore];
    label.fontSize = 40;
    label.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
    label.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/1, self.size.height/2);
    [self addChild:label];
    }

    return self;
}



-(void)addShip
{
    //initalizing spaceship node
    ship = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
    [ship setScale:0.5];
    ship.zRotation = - M_PI / 2;

    //Adding SpriteKit physicsBody for collision detection
    ship.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ship.size];
    ship.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = shipCategory;
    ship.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    ship.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = obstacleCategory | missileCategory;
    ship.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    ship.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    ship.name = @"ship";
    ship.position = CGPointMake(260,30);
    actionMoveRight = [SKAction moveByX:-30 y:0 duration:.2];
actionMoveLeft = [SKAction moveByX:30 y:0 duration:.2];

    [self addChild:ship];
}

- (void)shootMissile
{
// Sprite Kit knows that we are working with images so we don't need to pass the image’s                extension
missile = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"red-missile"];
[missile setScale:0.15];
// Position the missile outside the top
int r = arc4random() % 200;
missile.position = CGPointMake(20 + r, self.size.height + missile.size.height/2);


missile.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:missile.size];
missile.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = missileCategory;
missile.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
missile.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = shipCategory;
missile.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
missile.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;

// Add the missile to the scene
[self addChild:missile];

// Here is the Magic
// Run a sequence
[missile runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                        // Move the missile and Specify the animation time
                                        [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-(self.size.height + missile.size.height) duration:5],
                                        // When the missile is outside the bottom
                                        // The missile will disappear
                                        [SKAction removeFromParent]
                                        ]
                    ]];
}

- (void)updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:(CFTimeInterval)timeSinceLast {

self.lastSpawnTimeInterval += timeSinceLast;
if (self.lastSpawnTimeInterval > 5) {
    self.lastSpawnTimeInterval = 0;
    [self shootMissile];
}
}
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
// Handle time delta.
// If we drop below 60fps, we still want everything to move the same distance.
CFTimeInterval timeSinceLast = currentTime - self.lastUpdateTimeInterval;
self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
if (timeSinceLast > 1) { // more than a second since last update
    timeSinceLast = 1.0 / 60.0;
    self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
}

[self updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:timeSinceLast];

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];
if(touchLocation.x >ship.position.x){
    if(ship.position.x < 270){
        [ship runAction:actionMoveLeft];
    }
}else{
    if(ship.position.x > 50){

        [ship runAction:actionMoveRight];
    }
}
}

- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;
if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;
}
else
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyB;
    secondBody = contact.bodyA;
}

if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & shipCategory) != 0 &&
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask & obstacleCategory) != 0)
{

    score ++;
    if (score > HighScore) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score] forKey:@"HighScore"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
        SKScene * gameOverScene = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
        [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition: reveal];
    }
}

if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & shipCategory) != 0 &&
    (secondBody.categoryBitMask & missileCategory) != 0)
{
    // Do your stuff here
}
}
@end
```